# Tomcat Server in Eclipse and Virtual Machines

Tags: java

I have a question concerning my Tomcat Server on which 2 modules are running at the same time. Is a seperate Virtual Machine used for every module or are they all on one?

I haven't had any luck with searching on the web, so if anybody could answer this i would be very grateful.

Thank you

Comment: One Virtual machine by Tomcat with possibly separate classloaders will be used.

Comment: Could you provide a Source for that? Thank you!

Comment: I don't have source (that is the reason why I commented instead of answer), but that is my experience. You may do few things, 1) you may check process, services on machine etc., 2) You may use applications like JConsole etc., 3) There is some good documentation on Oracle website regarding classloader that may help. Remember you can do some customization to span separate JVM, but it is very very rare in general applications.

Comment: There is plenty of documentation about this at the Tomcat site.

Comment: @EJP I don't find anything specific about the question on the Tomcat site. I found something about ClassLoaders but not about the JVM. Could you link me the exact site, that you are speaking of? Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one virtual machine will be run.

Comment: Could you provide a source for that? I would like to understand the background a bit. Thank you!